# How to set counter views using the session?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, count

I had a table called file where all the details of files were recorded.

Now I want to put counter views of these files creating a new column called visitors in the same table.

The counter will increment according to the session. So when a user opens the file in website, the counter should automatically increment + 1.

I have this code

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once"config.php";

$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);


$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM files WHERE webpage='$webpage'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($num_rows == 0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO files (id, webpage, visitors)
VALUES ('','$webpage','1')");

}else{

if (!isset($_SESSION['webpage'])){$_SESSION['webpage'] = 0;
mysql_query("UPDATE counter SET visitors=visitors+1 WHERE webpage='$webpage'");}}

?>
```

And I am trying to relate to the session using URI of the page

```
$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

I do not know how to update the URI of the page automatically when user opens the file. This URI will be used to increment the visitors.

If there are any other ways to do it without the URI then can you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 months old -- I stumbled across it on a search. It was helpful, but only as a starting point. If somebody else stumbles across this, start with this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$webpage=htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
mysqli_query($sqllink, "INSERT INTO files (webpage, visitors) VALUES ($webpage, 1) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visitors = visitors + 1;");
?>
```